# Python bytearray to send unicode between sockets

Tags: python, sockets, unicode

I have set up my two first sockets. On the client side I want to send unicode strings. Then on the server side I'll make the string .upper() and return it to be printed. I managed to do this with a line of code on the server side:

```
modifiedMessage = message.decode('utf8').upper().encode('utf8')
```

Now I want to do this, by using this function:

```
def unicodeBin(message):
utf8_byte_array = bytearray(format(message))
uba = []
for n in range (len(format(message))):
    uba.append("{0:08b}".format(utf8_byte_array[n]))
    modifiedMessage = ' '.join(uba)
return modifiedMessage
```

I do not have much understanding of this code because as we just started python in my uni, but I get most of it. I've read on the bytearray function etc.

Is there a way I can add .upper() in this last piece of code to uppercase the message I've sent, and then return it, while being unicode?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: "a string".encode("utf-8")
Out[1]: 'a string'

In [2]: "a string".upper().encode("utf-8")
Out[2]: 'A STRING'

In [3]: "a string".encode("utf-8").upper()
Out[3]: 'A STRING'

In [4]: u"a string".upper()
Out[4]: u'A STRING'

In [5]: "a string".decode("utf-8").upper()
Out[5]: u'A STRING'

In [6]: u"a string".encode("utf-8").upper()
Out[6]: 'A STRING'

In [7]: u"a string".encode("utf-8").upper().decode("utf-8")
Out[7]: u'A STRING'
```

That's Python 2.7 by the way. I don't quite see why you'd need all the decoding and encoding in between. Unicode strings behave the same way as ASCII strings in Python 2.7, and in Python 3 byte and bytearray sequences still have .lower() and .upper() methods.